# How to Fix: Nginx Conflicting Server Name

Tags: nginx

I have three nginx server blocks:

One: **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Two: **/etc/nginx/sites-available/example1.com**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/example1.com/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example1.com www.example1.com;

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        }

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
 include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem; # manag$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Three: **/etc/nginx/sites-available/example2.com**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/example2.com/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example2.com www.example2.com;

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

        }

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
 include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

When i run: $ sudo nginx -t

This answer appears:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example1.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example1.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example1.com" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example1.com" on [::]:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

**How do you fix it?**

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -T`.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton check here: [link](https://pastebin.com/vCjw57pU)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the complete file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example1.com`. For some reason you only posted part of the file. But you can see the complete file in the `nginx -T` output.

When you ran certbot it added a second `server` block to the bottom of the file for serving port 80 and redirecting to HTTPS. It added HTTPS and port 443 to the original server block. But it didn't remove the port 80 listener from it. You can fix this yourself by removing the lines which make your new HTTPS server block listen on port 80.

Comment: do you mean this part? can you fix it? @MichaelHampton
`listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot`

Comment: Not that part. Look at the end of the file, where the second `server` block has been added.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: would you please put up a full display of corrected config file?  I've got this same problem with certbot edits and I don't know how to correctly fix.